# How to autofill the excel form based on the cell in the active worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, autofill

[image]

I created an Excel form and expect the textbox in the form able to be auto-filled by the value in cell B2. I had tried but seems like my code in VBA didn't work for me. I attached my code below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    With UserForm1
        .txtTextBox1.Value = Sheet7.Range("B10").Value
        
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Some obvious mistakes I see: you reference `B10` but your value is in `B2` - The event you put it on is the click event of the form, which seems like an odd place to put it, but it works if you click on the form as expected. Were you maybe trying to put it on the form `Initialize` event instead? This also assumes that the sheet's `code name` is `Sheet7` (a code name is not the same as the sheet name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form `Initialize` event like below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B10") 'Change sheet1 to your sheet name.
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun24HR, may I know the form will define it as a text or number if my value in cell `B10` is a number instead of text?

Comment: A textbox on a form is always treated as text, never a number.

Comment: Is the VBA code able to work if it is not a textbox but an option button? Which means based on cell `B10`  the code able to choose the correct option button based on the value of cell `B10`

Comment: @Elvis Then need some modification to code. It will.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a separate question with sample data to excel sheet and options buttons to form and with your desired result.